# Using a PHP array within a MySQL/PDO WHERE IN statement

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo, sql-injection

I'd like to safely use an array of strings within a `WHERE IN` SQL statement. For example:

```
$myArray = array('a','b','c');
```

Would be converted to something like

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE name IN ('a','b','c');
```

We could do this in an unsafe manner by doing something like

```
$in = "WHERE IN " . implode(",",$myArray);
```

But that is completely insecure from SQL injection.

We could use `preg_replace` to strip out unwanted characters, but that might be limiting.

We could use `addslashes` but I'm not confident that would be injection safe.

We could use `PDO::quote`. This might work like this:

```
function pdoQuote($val) { global $conn; return $conn->quote($val); }
$in = "WHERE IN " . implode(",", array_map('pdoQuote',$myArray));
```

But the docs clearly say:

> If you are using this function to build SQL statements, you are strongly recommended to use PDO::prepare() to prepare SQL statements with bound parameters instead of using PDO::quote() to interpolate user input into an SQL statement. Prepared statements with bound parameters are not only more portable, more convenient, immune to SQL injection, but are often much faster to execute than interpolated queries, as both the server and client side can cache a compiled form of the query.

Plus, it looks a bit messy, right?

We could also do something like a for loop to add the values to the query, and another for loop to bind them, but that does lead to lengthy and/or messy code.

My question: Is there a simple, safe way, that is only a single line (or so), of converting a PHP array into an SQL `WHERE IN` statement, that is has no security issues?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Where does this array come from? Is it user submitted? Surely you have a list of safe options?

Comment: The answer to your question is `no`. It will take more than 1 line.

Comment: there is no simple a one-line way with vanilla PDO. Thought you can always write such a helper function yourself

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton it's essentially wrong question to ask. it should be nobody's business whether the data is "user submitted" or not

Comment: @YourCommonSense What? I was asking because if it's not user submitted, then OP doesn't need to do anything special to it. It is injection proof if users cannot alter it.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton you cannot be more wrong. Besides, a programmer could busy himself with more important things than investigating the origin of the data they are dealing with

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thank you - if I were to write a helper function (which seems sensible) what would it look like? Would it use PDO->quote? Perhaps you could post an answer with this as a potential solution?

Comment: @Ben by no means it should be quote but prepare like in the linked question. I already posted, if you didn't notice, check the top of your question

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton the data is unfortunately based on user input (more specifically, returned from an AJAX call), otherwise as you say I wouldn't need to check for SQL injection. There may be a way to do what you suggest and check a look up of some kind - that's probably not going to answer the question above, but is a sensible way forward if possible.

Comment: @Ben If you had an array of _possibilities_, `$possible = ["col1", "col2", "col3"];`, then you could just loop the array through and check if the value is contained in the possible array. `foreach($user_input as $value) { if(!in_array($value, $possible)) die("INVALID PARAMETER"); }` If the user input is not a `$possible` value, then stop processing the page and return an error or whatever.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton your ideas are impractical and dangerous. JFYI. Following your habit, you are chewing on some *imaginary* cases. Get more experience with real world issues.

Comment: @GrumpCrouton, makes sense, however in this example there would be 100,000s of possible values so this isn't really an option. I'd really like to find a way to safely prepare a string along the lines of `mysql_real_escape_string` if that's possible.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Instead of just saying it's "impractical and dangerous", how about you explain to me _how_ or _why_? Because I don't see how that solution is either of those things. If there were only a handful of possible valid inputs, then that solution is _very_ practical, and would work just fine safety wise.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton it's impractical because for the values stored in the database, it's *SQL query* which is used to validate. Which makes your extra validation an overkill

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton why add another level to your database interaction? Why can't you use *the same generic approach for* all queries? Your suggestion makes sense for the field names, and for them it's ok. But for the data stored in the database it's a rather pointless overkill

Comment: @YourCommonSense I believe the best solution here is indeed to use bound parameters and have managed to do this with minimal changes to the code. Happy to post the solution if you're able to re-open the question.

Comment: @Ben I believe that existing solution is optimal enough